# Use iText 5 with Extended Latin-A encoding without IDENTITY_H character encoding?

Tags: pdf, encoding, itext, iso-8859-1

We are still using iText 5 and have a new requirement to support Latin Extended-A character encodings. If we use IDENTITY_H with, say, Arial Unicode, this is entirely possible. But since we cannot ship Arial Unicode with our software, we would like to use the normal Arial font (which supports Latin Extended-A).
Is this possible with iText 5? Or do we need iText 7's IExtraEncoding interface to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried yet to use *the normal Arial font* with IDENTITY_H?

Comment: @mkl Yes and that works, but I wasn't sure if this was the best solution...

Comment: It's the easiest solution.